# How to use ajax in django, to pass the model object and store it in database without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views, django-ajax-selects

I'm doing a small project in Django, in that I thought of adding a favorite button in one of the pages so that on clicking on that button it has to return the model object and it has to be stored in another database for the reference, but it's not happening
Here is my 
**home/bookdetails.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'home/Base.html' %}

{% block title %} Book Details {% endblock %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/home/css/heart.css">
<script src="{% static 'js/heart.css' %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>

{% block body %}

{% if error_message %}<p><strong> {{ error_message }} </strong></p>{% endif %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sub").click(function(event) {
 var userbooks = '{{ userbooks }}';
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'home:favoriteAjax' %}"
            data:{userbbooks:userbooks}
            datatype:'json'
            success: function() {
            alert("successfully added to favorites")
            }
        }
        });
});
});

</script>
<p>Book name:{{ userbooks.book_name }}</p><br>
<p>Book author:{{ userbooks.book_author }}</p><br>
<p>Book genre:{{ userbooks.book_genre }}</p><br>
<p>Book ISBN:{{ userbooks.book_ISBN }}</p><br>
<button type="submit" id="sub" onclick="changeText()">Favourite</button>

{% endblock %}
```

**my urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='home'
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.HomeView,name='home'),
    path('addBooks/',views.addBooks,name='addBooks'),
    path('myBooks/',views.BooksView.as_view(),name='myBooks'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.BookDetailsView.as_view(), name='myBooks'),
    path('search/', views.SearchedBooks.as_view(), name='searchedBooks'),
    path('favorite_ajax/', views.favorite_ajax, name='favoriteAjax'),
    ]
```

**my models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserBooks(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_ISBN=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("username", "book_ISBN"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name

class FavBooks(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    book_id= models.ForeignKey(UserBooks,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user_id", "book_id"),)
```

**my views.py:**

```
def favorite_ajax(request):
    if(request.method=='GET'):
        book=request.GET['userbooks']
        fav=FavBooks()
        fav.book_id=book
        fav.user_id=request.user
        fav.save()
    return HttpResponse("done")
```

I want to take the userbooks model object from the bookdetails.html through ajax call and want to store that reference in the FavBooks model. How could I make it happen? Thanks!

Comment: `favorite_ajax` is a `POST` request not a `GET` request because you are updating your database not getting any data from it.

Comment: yeah i've changed it to post but its not working though

Comment: you have not defined a form tag anywhere in your html.

Comment: Does form tag is necessary?,i  want that button to act as trigger,to transfer the object,that's why i haven't used form tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right way of doing it:

html:

```
 <form id="form_id" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit">Favourite</button>
 </form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#form_id").on('submit', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); 
       var userbooks = '{{ userbooks }}';
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "{% url 'home:favoriteAjax' %}",
           data:{
                 userbooks:userbooks, 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
           },
           datatype:'json',
           success: function(data) {
             if (data['success'])
                alert("successfully added to favorites")
           }
       }); 
  });
```

views.py:

```
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 def favorite_ajax(request):
   data = {'success': False} 
   if request.method=='POST':
      book = request.POST.get('userbooks')
      fav = FavBooks()
      fav.book_id = book
      fav.user_id = request.user
      fav.save()
      data['success'] = True
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: i ve made the changes you suggested it was raising page isn't working error HTTP 405

Comment: change this `url: "{% url 'home:favoriteAjax' %}",` to this `url: "/home/favoriteAjax/",`

Comment: check your browser console does it show any error ?

Comment: After having a look at console i found that there is an extra curly brace i ve removed it ,now it was not showing any error but it was not displaying an success message and data has not entered the data base instead in console it  was showing error like POST http://localhost:8000/home/favoriteAjax/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: check your terminal from where you are running the site. It would have extra information what is causing the problem.

Comment: it was showing this: ValueError at /home/favoriteAjax/
Cannot assign "'alc'": "FavBooks.book_id" must be a "UserBooks" instance.alc is the instance i want to add to the database

Comment: change this: `fav.book_id = book` to this: `fav.book_id = book.id`

Comment: what that means is that when you send `userbooks` object from your template to your view via jQuery. It converts it to a string and sends it to django. What you can do is that you can either convert this string back to `userbooks` object by desalinising, Or you can access the `id` field of this string and filter your `userbooks` object by passing it the `id`.

Comment: yeah !! its working now i have passed the book id instead of object,thank you very much ;):)